# How to to hide switch from cell?

Tags: swift

How to hide switch from cell when barbutton title edit change into done how it possible?

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing,animated:animated)

    if self.isEditing{

        self.editButtonItem.title = "Done"
        tableview.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        tableview.reloadData()

    }
    else{
        self.editButtonItem.title = "Edit"
        tableview.setEditing(false, animated: false)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the setEditing method you can access for all visible rows this way

```
tableView.visibleCells.forEach{ cell in
       //define your custom cell class
       If let customCell = cell as? YourCustomCellCalss{
      //call here the method to show/hide the switch or whatever you have for hiding it
     customCell.hideSwitch()
     }
}
```

But it will change only visible rows, so you need to add a checking for self.isEditing in you cellForRowAt method for all rows that will be dequeued after scrolling to show/hide the switch

If my code differs from your custom cell implementation, then please add more of your code in the question

Let me know if you'll need something

Comment: Manipulating the view (the cell) is always a bad idea. At the moment the user scrolls you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Scrolling will call cellForRow each time, so you won't get unexpected behavior if you will handle it in the cellForRow method. Also there is not a good idea to reload whole table only to make one outlet hidden, if the cell contains data, it will cost for more memory usage

Comment: `reloadData` considers also only the visible cells and it can be assumed that there is more than one cell containing a switch.

Comment: But what if your table reload will call animations or fetching something like images on each reuse? In this case you will call that each editing but you don't need such behavior. So you will have to make more changes in your code while you just need to change one outlet state without reusing the cell. Could you provide some example for me why it can be bad? Maybe your experience will help me to change my code here and in my current project then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden property of switch. like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "democell", for: indexPath) as! DemoViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        if self.isEditing{
          cell.yourSwitch.isHidden = false
    }
    else{
        cell.yourSwitch.isHidden = false
    }


        return cell
    }
```